# Noise variance calculation for 16APSK Demodulator

Tags: noise, digital-communications, snr, qpsk

I need to use approximate LLR algorithm for 16APSK demodulation. For that, I need to calculate noise variance which is given as

$Noise\;variance = \frac {Signal\;power\;\times\;Symbol\;time}{Sample\;time\;\times\;10^{\frac{Es/No}{10}}}$

I have the following informations
SNR = 10, Signal Power = unity.
Number of bits/symbol = 4,
Code rate = 8/9

How can I know symbol time and sample time values? If I have to assume, what are the typical assumptions? 
And if Es/No = SNR? or it is dependent on  symbol time and sample time?
So far I have assumed Symbol time = Sample time.
Though I can understand symbol time, I am unable to comprehend the meaning of sample time in  this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to take into account the oversampling operation.

Symbol time = sample time implies no oversampling.

See [AWGN model](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/awgn-channel.html) for more details about the conversion among EbN0, EsN0 and SNR.

> For example, if a complex baseband signal is oversampled by a factor of 4, then EsNo exceeds the corresponding SNR by $10\log_{10}(4)$.